# How to get rid of height differences in two beamer blocks?

Tags: beamer, height, block

How come the two blocks have a different height?
What should be changed in \hole definition in order to have the same height?

```
\documentclass[10pt,lmodern,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue!20}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=blue!5}
\newcommand\hole[1]{%
    \alt<handout>{\invisible<1->{#1}}{#1}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%--------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some title}
\framesubtitle{Some subtitle}
Some text.
\begin{block}{A block}
    Text:
    %
    \begin{align*}
        ax=b
    \end{align*}
    %
\end{block}
\begin{block}{A block}
    \hole{Text:
    %
    \begin{align*}
        ax=b
    \end{align*}
    %
    }
\end{block}
Why is there a difference in the two blocks' height? How to get rid of that?
\end{frame}

%---------------%
\end{document}
%---------------%
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to place a `%` after the closing brace of the `\hole`?

Comment: I don't know where the space comes from but using `\visible` or `\invisible` introduces it. Try with `\begin{block}{A block}\visible<1->{Text:\begin{align*}ax=b\end{align*}}\end{block}` or `\begin{block}{A block}\invisible<1->{Text:\begin{align*}ax=b\end{align*}}\end{block}` without spaces at all and compare with the first block.

Comment: @Ignasi: Looks like an issue with the `\invisible` command. If you use `\only` instead (in OP's original code), no extra space is added (but of course this is not achieving the desired result of invisibility).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a `\par` before closing `\hole` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,lmodern,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue!20}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=blue!5}
\newcommand\hole[1]{%
    \alt<handout>{\invisible<1->{#1}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some title}
\framesubtitle{Some subtitle}
Some text.
\begin{block}{A block}
    Text:
    \begin{align*}
        ax=b
    \end{align*}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{A block}
    \hole{Text:
    \begin{align*}
        ax=b
    \end{align*}\par
    }
\end{block}
There's no difference in the two blocks' height!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Of course, you could also change the definition of `\hole` to something like

```
\newcommand\hole[1]{%
    \alt<handout>{\invisible<1->{#1\par}}{#1}%
}
```

What's causing the problem? Quite frankly, I've no real idea (although I have some suspicion). In any case, a [`related question`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223492/3954) inquiring for the cause of the problem was asked by **Kevin_C**.