# Beamer: Extra vertical space with \visible

Tags: beamer, spacing, overlays

This is related to

> [How to get rid of height differences in two beamer blocks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223469/how-to-get-rid-of-height-differences-in-two-beamer-blocks)

I'm curious why overlay commands `\visible` (and `\invisible`, `\uncover`, `\onslide`) would add an extra vertical space after the equation; whereas `\only` (and `\alt`) does not.

Does it somehow have to do with the fact that `\visible` et al (except `\onslide`) are defined using `\alt`? (Definitions are found in `..\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamerbaseoverly.sty`).

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\newcommand\entry{
  Text:
  %
  \begin{equation*}
      ax=b
  \end{equation*}
  %
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{No overlay command}
  \entry
\end{block}
\begin{block}{\textbackslash visible, or \textbackslash invisible, \textbackslash uncover, \textbackslash onslide}
  \visible<1->{\entry}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{\textbackslash only or \textbackslash alt}
  \only<1->{\entry}%
  % {\entry} % uncomment if using \alt
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: I don't know what's causing the odd behaviour, but adding an explicit `\par` before leaving `\visible` (as in `\visible<1->{\entry\par}`)solves the problem (that's the answer I provided to the original question you linked to).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for the comment. It seems that adding other texts after `\entry`, either inside or outside of the scope of `\visible` (e.g. `\visible<1->{\entry} text`) also worked. Somehow the combination of `\visible` and display math gives the unwanted vertical space.

Comment: Solved in comments or does the problem still exists?

Comment: @samcarter: Thanks for your interest in this question. As far as getting rid of the extra space goes, the problem is solved. But I'm also interested in what's causing the problem---the *why*. And this has not been addressed by Gonzalo's comment. Perhaps you could shed some light on this matter, since you are quite a Beamer expert here.

Comment: @HerrK. Thanks for your kind words! But to answer this one would have to dig through `beamerbaseoverlay.sty`. My best bet is, this is caused by either by `\beamer@spacingcover` or by additional groups which are introduced with the `\visible` command in comparison to `\only`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The final answer is the following:

> When `\[display math\]` encounters `\par`, it will cancel the space after `\]`.

This can be proved by simply switching back to `$$old display math$$`.

Ironically, in one of the most highly voted question [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to), people say that **the spacing of `$$` is wrong** and **`$$` is obsolete**.

## Why and why not `\]` encounters `\par`

Usually we just write `\[1+1\]` so everything goes fine. But as for overlay specification, we need to put our stuff in brackets. And it is `{\[1+1\]}` that separates `\]` from `\par`, so the space remains.

## `\only`, `\alt`, and other overlay specifications

Beamer does a lot of works regarding overlay specification. But sometimes it just reuses the existing command. For example `\visible` is ultimately defined as

> ```
>  \def\visible{\alt{\do_nothing}{\hide_what_follows}}
> ```

So `\visible<2->{\[1+1\]}` will become

```
\alt<2->{\do_nothing}{\hide_what_follows}{\[1+1\]}
```

and here `\[1+1\]` is surrounded by brackets.
⟶ `\]` does not encounter `\par`.
⟶ the space remains.

---

If we add an explicit `\par` like this `\visible<2->{\[1+1\]\par}`, it will become

```
\alt<2->{\do_nothing}{\hide_what_follows}{\[1+1\par\]}
```

and here `\]` encounters `\par`.
⟶ the space is canceled.

---

On the other hand, whenever we use `\alt` directly, we usually write

```
\alt<2->{}{\[1+1\]}
```

In this case, the surrounding brackets is not a problem because TeX will remove it during macro expansion.
⟶ `\]` encounters `\par`.
⟶ the space is canceled.